# Drop down list not showing as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have created a dropdown list in a web app. To make the list I wanted, I had to put two attributes together, FirstName & LastName, by querying and creating a new variable 'Display'. Now, instead of showing "FirstName LastName" for each item is shows: { Display = FirstName LastName}

Is there a way to remove the variable and brackets?

C# Code:

```
var professors = _context.Professor.Include(p => p.Courses).Select( p => new {Display = $"{p.FirstName} {p.LastName}"});

ProfessorDropDown = new SelectList (await professors.Distinct().ToListAsync());
```

Razor Page:

```
<select asp-for= "Prof" asp-items="Model.ProfessorDropDown">
            <options value="">--Select Professor--</options>
        </select>
```

Comment: Do you not need to have a value for your optioons too?

Comment: I have values seeded into the database. Right now they are all showing in the drop down, it's just not showing cleanly.

In the dropdown I'd like just a select all (using ---Select Professor---) here. Ideally, after an option is selected, just the information connect with that option would be shown.

Comment: Did you try `new SelectList (await professors.Distinct().ToListAsync(), "Display", "Display")`

Comment: Ah! That worked. Thank you.